# How to customize vertical distance in 'underlying'

Tags: equations

This seems to be a dummy one but I haven't found anything that works good for me.

I'm working in an article and I need to get an underlined expression, like this 
[image]

I mean REALLY CLOSE, but, so far, the available options such as `\underlying{x}` or `\underset{_}{x}` haven't worked so good because it left a huge vertical space. I need it to be real close of `x`. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

A `\underline` seems to work great:

[image]

If there is still too much space with you can draw your own `\rule` and tweak the placement as desired:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\ux}{\underline{x}}

\newcommand*{\LineWidth}{0.4pt}
\newcommand*{\YShiftContent}{-0.65ex}
\newcommand*{\YShiftRule}{0.5ex}
\newcommand*{\BaselineAdjust}{-0.4ex}
\newcommand{\ru}[1]{\raisebox{\BaselineAdjust}{$\substack{\textstyle #1\\[\YShiftContent]\rule[\YShiftRule]{\widthof{#1}}{\LineWidth}}$}}


\begin{document}   
\[ \int_{R_1} f_x (\ux \mid C_1)\dd \ux \]
or using \verb|\ru| macro:
\[ \int_{R_1} f_x (\ru{x} \mid C_1)\dd \ru{x} \]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need an underline symbol that's shorter than what's produced by `\underline`, you could turn to the [ushort](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/ushort) package and its `\ushort` macro. The first line below uses the `\ushort` macro, the second the `\underline` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ushort,amsmath}
\newcommand{\dee}{\operatorname{d\!}{}} % "differential" operator
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/178948/5001
\setlength\textwidth{2in} % just for this example
\begin{document}   
\[ \int_{R_1} f_x (\ushort{x} \mid C_1)\dee \ushort{x} \]
vs. 
\[ \int_{R_1} f_x (\underline{x} \mid C_1)\dee \underline{x} \]
\end{document}
```