# Better automatic spacing of differential d?

Tags: spacing, typography, math-operators

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14821/whats-the-proper-way-to-typeset-a-differential-operator) was basically about whether the differential d should be upright or italicized, not about how to achieve that in tex. However, [this useful answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27978/6853) did suggest something like the following for typesetting it:

```
\newcommand{\der}{\operatorname{d\!}}
```

This is what I've been doing for a while, but I find that there are a few cases where the spacing is wrong. This code

```
\der(x^7) \quad \der x \quad \operatorname{d} (x^7) \quad \operatorname{d} x
```

gives output that looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

The negative thin space looks good for typesetting dx, but bad for d(x^7). Is there a good way to define a single `\der` macro that automagically gets both cases right, or is my best option to define two macros and pick one or the other as needed?

Comment: You should have a look at package `physics`.

Comment: A common definition seen in many, many places is `\newcommand*\der{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`\operatorname` turns `d` into an operator. If an ordinary math atom follows (`x`), then TeX sets a thin space that is negated by `\!`. However, TeX does not set a space after an operator if the following math atom belongs to categories "open", "close", "punct", or "inner" (`\scriptstyle`/`\scriptscriptstyle`). A fix would be to add an empty math ord atom (`\mathord{}` or an empty sub formula `{}`), then TeX always sets a thin space, canceled by `\!`. Macro `\der` behaves on the left-hand side as an operator and on its right-hand side as an ordinary math atom. Now both cases work as expected:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\der}{\operatorname{d\!}{}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \der(x^7) \quad \der x
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Variation

The `d` can be put both in the operator atom or the ordinary atom, as suggested in the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178946/better-automatic-spacing-of-differential-d/178948?noredirect=1#comment413139_178946) of Manuel and the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/178946/better-automatic-spacing-of-differential-d/178948?noredirect=1#comment413157_178948) of egreg (without `\mathrm`):

```
\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}
```

### Fonts for `d`

- `\lim`, `\sin` and friends are using the font `\operator@font`. Package `amsmath` then provides macro `\operatorname`. But the former can also be
  used without an additional package:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand*{\der}{%
    \mathop{\kern\z@\operator@font d}\!{}%
  }
  \makeatother
  ```

  `\kern\z@` prevents that `\mathop` centers the symbol.

  Or with `d` in the ordinary atom:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \newcommand*{\der}{%
    \mathop{}\!{\operator@font d}%
  }
  \makeatother
  ```
- Font `\mathrm` is easier to use (no `@` in the name):

  ```
  \newcommand*{\der}{%
    \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}%
  }
  ```

  or a little more complex, again the `\kern` prevents vertical centering:

  ```
  \newcommand*{\der}{%
    \mathop{\kern0pt\mathrm{d}}\!{}%
  }
  ```
- The italics variant:

  ```
  \newcommand*{\der}{%
    \mathop{}\!d%
  }%
  ```

  or

  ```
  \newcommand*{\der}{%
    \mathop{\kern0pt d}\!{}%
  }
  ```

  > [image: italics]

Comment: Is there any advantage or disadvantage of this compared to the definition suggested by Manuel in his comment?

Comment: @BenCrowell: Both versions consist of a math operator atom, negative kerning that cancels the automatically inserted thin space, and an ordinary atom. In the answer the `d` is put int the operator atom, the comment puts it in the ordinary atom, but the spacing is the same.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Did you try something like `$\der(x+y)$`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Oh, I didn't see the `{}`. I still prefer `\mathop{}\!d`; it's shorter and doesn't require other packages.

Comment: @egreg: I have now added lots of variations.

Answer (score 8):

Packages are written by good and nice people keeping lazy and ignorant people like me in mind. Instead of re-inventing things, it is better start finding a suitable package and use it. In this case, `physics` package (as noted by Johannes) offers `\dd` macro. A screen shot of the relevant part of the `physics` documentation:

[image]

And a sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \dd(x^7) \quad \dd x
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After seeing how `\dd` is defined in the package, I wish I didn't try reading it.

Comment: @egreg ???. Is it so wrong? Can you add explanations to the answers please, if you have some time? It is always good to know what is wrong in what I am using :(. I use `physics` too much.

Comment: I can't see what's the point in having a complicated definition when the usual one (`\mathop{}\!d`, add `\mathrm`, if you wish) works flawlessly in all cases; there's no advantage having `\dd[3]{x}` instead of the simpler (and clearer) `\dd^3 x`. There's surely *no* advantage in requiring `\dd{x}` instead of `\dd x`; of course with the usual definition, braces are optional.