# Setting new command in LaTeX for the differential

Tags: macros

I am writing a document in LaTeX and since I use quite often the command `${\rm d}$` for inserting the differential in the integrals , I decided to make a new command and insert in the preamble.

I wrote it as: `\newcommand{\d}{d}` but it does not compile. It say "your command has been ignored. What am I doing wrong here? How can I insert the command to work properly ?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14821/14757 or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178946/14757 or search for `differential` here in TEX.SE.

Comment: Please have a look at packages like `physics` or `skamth` or ...

Comment: you probably got the error `! LaTeX Error: Command \d already defined.`  `\d` is one of the "predefined" accent commands.  it's not a good idea to try to redefine it.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I did not know that. Anyway, thanks for the links. I'll check them out. It is that I do not use commands that often, expect for defing new theorems of new definitions or lemmas etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest

```
\newcommand{\dee}{\mathop{\mathrm{d}\!}}
```

to be used as follows:

```
\int_0^1 x\dee x = \frac{1}{2}
```

Comment: It is a good command. Also the links given above helped me declare a new command. Thank you!

Comment: @Tolaso No, it isn't good. Try `$\frac{\dee y}{\dee x}$` to know why.

Comment: @Tolaso - I've posted an improved version of the `\dee` macro, which should pass egreg's muster. :-)

Comment: @egreg Ohh... I did not try that. Thanks for the observation.