# How to produce suitable spaces surround the differential symbol d in dx?

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators

I'm creating a list with common math commands that I use, but \newcommand and \DeclareMathOperator both add a space after the symbol I just defined. For example, comparing the two commands defined below,

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{d}

% Derivartive in Leibniz notation d{#1}/d{#2}
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{ \frac{\mathrm{d}}#1 }{ \mathrm{d}#2^} }
\newcommand{\dderiv}[2]{ \frac{\dd #1 }{ \dd #2 } }
```

\deriv{f}{x} gives me the usual

[image]

while \dderiv{f}{x} is compiled to

[image]

I'm using Overleaf. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I believe that `\DeclareMathOperator` makes that space.  You can look through the various suggestions at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/244109/107497, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14821/107497, and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178946/107497.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\DeclareMathOperator` command gives the string `\mathop` spacing, like the `\log` or `\cos` operators.

To get `\mathord` (ordinary math atom) spacing, wrap it in braces:

```
\newcommand{\dderiv}[2]{ \frac{{\dd} #1 }{{\dd} #2 } }
```

The `\mathord{\dd}` command will also work, so it’s up to you whether this overcomplicates things or makes it easier to understand why you are wrapping `\dd`.

So, for a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{d}

% Derivative in Leibniz notation d{#1}/d{#2}
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{ \frac{\mathrm{d}#1 }{ \mathrm{d}#2} }
\newcommand{\dderiv}[2]{ \frac{{\dd} #1 }{{\dd} #2 } }

\begin{document}
\[ \dderiv{x}{t}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might, however, want operator-like spacing on the left but ordinary spacing on the right of `\dd`, for use cases like `\dd x \dd y`   For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\dd{\mathop{}\mathrm{d}}

% Derivartive in Leibniz notation d{#1}/d{#2}
\newcommand{\deriv}[2]{ \frac{\mathrm{d}#1 }{ \mathrm{d}#2} }
\newcommand{\dderiv}[2]{ \frac{\dd #1 }{\dd #2 } }

\begin{document}
\[ \iint 1 \dd x \dd y
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

##### ETA:

Several commenters thought the second example added excessive space, so I’ll reprint Henri Menke’s tweak from the comments:

```
\newcommand\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

Comment: Second example is based on an example by egreg, but he prefers an italic *d* operator.

Comment: The second solution is better. By the way, in fact, there should be spaces at the both sides of d, while people forms the habit that there is no space at the right side. But of course, we can think that d is not an operator.

Comment: @M.Logic If you want spaces on both sides, the OP already shows how.

Comment: @M.Logic I said `\mathord` was optional but unnecessary. You might or might not think it makes the command easier to read.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help

Comment: For me personally `\mathop{}\mathrm{d}` is a bit too generously spaced. I prefer `\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}`.

Comment: @Davislor Try `\dd(x+y)` to see why your definition is disputable.

Comment: @egreg How would you say d(x+y) should be spaced? It’s honestly not a notation I’ve seen very often.

Comment: @Davislor Sorry, it was a bad example. But your definition provides too wide a space anyway.

Comment: @egreg Henri Menke has posted a possible solution for that in a comment. Although I’m not completely sure it will never produce a negative space.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\dd}{d}
```

is wrong under many respects and won't work *anywhere* as intended.

I'm not referring to the “upright d” (which I consider mathematically wrong, but that's not the point), but to the space that `\dd` will *automatically* add when followed by an ordinary symbol.

What you want is

```
\newcommand{\dd}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

and all will go smooth.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\dd{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

% Derivartive in Leibniz notation d{#1}/d{#2}
\newcommand{\dderiv}[2]{ \frac{\dd #1 }{\dd #2 } }

\begin{document}

\[
\dderiv{f}{t} + \iint f(x,y) \dd x \dd y
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]