# long explanation in align environment; would like to split over two lines

Tags: formatting, align

I have an `align` environment as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\compose{\circ}
\newcommand\bd{\mathbf{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sum_i [\int_M (\phi_i f)\,\bd V] &= \sum_i [\int_A (\phi_i\compose \alpha)(f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)] && \text{by definition} \\
&= \int_A [\sum_i (\phi_i\compose \alpha)(f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)] &&  \text{because the sum converges uniformly on compact subsets of $A$} \\
&= \int_A [\sum_i (f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)] && \text{because $\sum_i (\phi_i\compose\alpha)=1$ on $A$} \\
&= \int_M f\,\bd V && \text{by definition.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The second explanation is too long. I would like to split it over two lines. If I make a whole new line in the `align` environment it looks terrible:

[image]

What's the best way to do this well? A `minipage`? How would I deal with the fact that `align` chooses widths itself whereas I need to provide a fixed width for `minipage`?

Comment: After all, you have to give some sort of indication as to where you want the explanation to be split: specifying the width of the `minipage` (or of a `\parbox[t]`) is just one of the ways to do so.

Comment: Ideally the text would just wrap at the margin.

Comment: @frakbak It's not possible to “wrap at the margin”: the width of the `align*` depends on all lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you think of this?  (I made a few more edits to the code.  Some comments explain the rationale, or give appropriate credits.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand*\compose{\circ}
\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathbf{d}} % Thanks to Heiko Oberdiek

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    \sum_i \biggl[\int_M (\phi_i f)\diff V\biggr]
        &= \sum_i \biggl[\int_A
            (\phi_i\compose\alpha)(f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)\biggr]
            && \mbox{by definition} \\
            % \mbox, for consistency.  Here I do not think it is wrong (see 
            % below), and it avoids the recourse to \mathchoice, which is 
            % relatively cumbersome since it typesets the argument four times 
            % (but who cares of such things nowadays?).
        &= \int_A \biggl[\sum_i
            (\phi_i\compose \alpha)(f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)\biggr]
            && \parbox[t]{10pc}{because the sum converges uniformly
                on compact subsets of~$A$\strut} \\ % please note the \strut
        &= \int_A \biggl[\sum_i (f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)\biggr]
            && \mbox{because $\sum_i (\phi_i\compose\alpha)=1$ on $A$} \\
            % Note the \textstyle \sum, automatic since \mbox does not patch 
            % \everymath as \text does.
        &= \int_M f\diff V
            && \mbox{by definition.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Although the box is not too narrow here, I'd still use `\raggedright` for the `\parbox` text:  `\parbox[t]{10pc}{\raggedright because the sum converges uniformly on compact subsets of
    $A$\strut}`

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Good suggestion, thank you.  But as long as luck is with us, and no overfull boxes occur, I’d rather maintain the justification.  Of course, after seeing the output, `\raggedright` could be added.

Comment: Thanks, I like the simplicity of this answer. But can you explain the `\strut`? What difference does it make?

Comment: Without it, the distance between the third and the second equation would depend on how the explanation is split, and on which letters end up in the last line.

Comment: the brackets around the sum and integral really look too small.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: You are right, but I did not even consider them, I just copied the code from the OP.  When I have a minute, I’ll edit my answer.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?
[image]

just put equation description in tabular environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\compose{\circ}
\newcommand\bd{\mathbf{d}}

    \begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sum_i [\int_M (\phi_i f)\,\bd V]
    &= \sum_i [\int_A (\phi_i\compose \alpha)(f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)]
        && \text{by definition} \\
    &= \int_A [\sum_i (\phi_i\compose \alpha)(f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)]
        &&  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
            because the sum converges uniformly\\
            on compact subsets of $A$
            \end{tabular}\\
&= \int_A [\sum_i (f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)] && \text{because $\sum_i (\phi_i\compose\alpha)=1$ on $A$} \\
&= \int_M f\,\bd V && \text{by definition.}
\end{align*}
    \end{document}
```

**Edit:** As @egreg say, spurious space before description you can eliminate with `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}`.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}` so you remove the unwanted space.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for pointed this. I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

A `tabular` can be used, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\newcommand\compose{\circ}
\newcommand*{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathbf{d}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sum_i \mleft[\int_M (\phi_i f)\diff V\mright]
  &= \sum_i \mleft[\int_A (\phi_i\compose \alpha)
     (f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)\mright]
  && \text{by definition} \\
  &= \int_A \Bigl[\sum_i (\phi_i\compose \alpha)
     (f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)\Bigr]
  && \text{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    because the sum\\
    converges uniformly on\\
    compact subsets of $A$\end{tabular}} \\
  &= \int_A \Bigl[\sum_i
     (f\compose\alpha)V(D\alpha)\Bigr]
  && \text{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    because\\ $\textstyle\sum_i (\phi_i\compose\alpha)=1$
    on $A$\end{tabular}} \\
  &= \int_M f\diff V && \text{by definition.}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- The square brackets are enlarged via the `\left` and `\right` feature.
  Actually package `mleftright` with `\mleft` and `\mright` provides a version of `\left` and `\right` that avoids additional horizontal space.
- The square brackets in the second and third line are enlarged with `\Bigl` and `\Bigr` to avoid too large brackets, which would also cover the subscript.
- Macro `\diff` is defined instead of `\bd`. The definition with the starting `\mathop{}` here avoids the manual setting of `\,` before.
- The sum symbol in the explanation is set in `\textstyle` instead of `\displaystyle`, because it is part of the text and not of the displayed equation. This form fits better into text lines.

Comment: Sorry, but the `\mleft` brackets in the second and third lines are really ugly.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, fixed with the manual `\Bigl[` and `\Bigr` instead of `\(m)left` and `\(m)right`.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek Do you mind explaining what `\mathop{}` does? I understand the incorporation of the space (`\,` or `\!`) into the definition. I prefer to leave that out because I like to play with the spacing sometimes.

Comment: @frakbak See question ["Better automatic spacing of differential d?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/178946/16967). A table for the spacing between the math atoms can be found in "The TeXbook" by D. E. Knuth or in V. Eijkhout's ["TeX by Topic"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf). Analyze your cases, probably you will need less or even no manual fiddling with `\mathop{}` included.